# Initializing a text input default value with data coming from state supplies the text input with old state data

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn the MERN stack and have been trying to create a simple CRUD app. I'm done with the create, read, and delete but I'm stuck at initializing text inputs.

I click a link to redirect with an ID in the URI as a param. When the component renders, I have an action inside a useEffect hook to retrieve the document in mongoDB using the ID param. This action updates the state which I want to use when initializing my text inputs.

My problem is the text input is initialized but is behind.

I tried putting my action in the link's onClick but I still get the same results.

Here is my link that redirects to a component:

```
<Link
 to={{ pathname: `/${client._id}` }}
>
```

Here is my form:

```
const Form = ({client, getClient}) => {
 useEffect(() => {
  getClient(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
 }, [getClient]}

const [formData, setFormData = useState({
 name: client ? client.name : ''
});

const { name } = formData;

return (
 <input
  type='text'
  placeholder='* Name'
  name='name'
  value={name}
  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
 />
)
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  client: state.client,
});

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 { getClient }
)(withRouter(Form));
```

Here is what happens:

1. Click link 1 and redirect
2. No value inside text input
3. Go back
4. Click link 2 and redirect
5. Text input has value but the name is from link 1

Am I approaching the problem correctly?

Comment: i would day maintain a state and dont render that <input /> until ur data arrives from useEffect, ( like ```dataRetriveState && <input />``` ) , make a callback in ```getClient(..., (data) => data && setDataRetriveState(true))```

Comment: did you applied my suggeston ?

Comment: I'm still trying but no luck yet.

Comment: Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Yes, I'm using react-router.

Comment: Take a look at [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) from `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I'll post it in case someone runs into the same problem.

It was the second parameter in my useEffect hook. I didn't put the state I needed whenever it changes.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  // Stuff
 }, [*state that was changing*]}
```